# Custom NPM package - Exposing Internal Interfaces to custom npm package

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I have some npm packages that are used internally in company projects, and I would like to expose some of the interfaces used by dependencies from this component.

So if I have a project for a npm package (called company-utils) that has a dependency with `axios`, and I want to expose a method that creates an instance for axios, how can I export it so other projects that installs this company-utils can see the `axios` interfaces/methods/etc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you are using this company-utils as a wrapper for axios? If you want to export something you can put an index.js at the root of the package and export it there. Then it will be exposed to anyone who installs the package.

so the structure will be:

- package

  - src/
  - index.js
  - package.json

Then inside index.js

```
import method from 'src/<path to method file>'
export method
```

If you install the package into another project that method will be exposed

```
import method from 'package'
```